# Why do I occasionally get an error message when sending mail using .NET and Office365 SMTP server?

Tags: .net, email, send, smtpclient

I use the following code to send test e-mails using the Office 365 SMTP server. Trouble is that sometimes it doesn't work (it returns the error below) and if I retry it a few seconds later then it works.  Why is it so unreliable?  Does it have to do with my code or is it an issue with the network/SMTP server?

```
Public Sub SendEMail(ByVal fromAddress As String, ByVal toAddress As String, ByVal subject As String, ByVal body As String)
Try
    Using message As New MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body)
        message.Body = body
        Dim mailClient As New SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587)

        mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        mailClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
        mailClient.EnableSsl = True
        mailClient.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(UserName, Password)

        mailClient.Send(message)
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & vbCrLf & ex.InnerException.ToString)
End Try
```

Error Message (when it doesn't work):

Failure sending mail.
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 read, Boolean readLine)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLines(SmtpReplyReader caller, Boolean oneLine)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLine(SmtpReplyReader caller)
at System.Net.Mail.CheckCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, String& response)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)

Comment: `mailClient` is an `IDisposable` and should be in a `Using`. Alternatively, save on establishing the connection repeatedly, by caching it in a field, and disposing it using `IDisposable` on the outer class. It's very possible the server will block you if you open too many connections inn a short space of time, so it's advisable to do this. It also conserves your limited quantity of high numbered TCP ports on the client

Comment: Charlieface, my version of SmtpClient does not have a Dispose method

Comment: You should probably still cache it though. I take it you are not on .Net 4.0+, as it has been documented as far back as that to be `IDisposable`. Can I suggest you upgrade to a supported version? .Net 3.5 with Service Pack 1 is supported, but I imagine it's only getting security fixes

Comment: Even after upgrading to .NET 4 and making use of **Using** (for mailClient) it still fails sporadically.